# Как размержить файл?

Tags: git

Например, я мержу ветки между собой и у меня возникли конфликты, которые я некорректно решил.

Как я могу отменить мерж в этом файле и начать по новой?

Как я могу размержить всю ветку, чтобы выполнить мерж с самого начала?

Comment: `git revert` с опцией -m чтоб указать, какой из парентов главный, а какой был с ветки, которую сливали. Номер парента брать из `git log`

Answer (score 0):

> Как я могу размержить всю ветку, чтобы выполнить мерж с самого начала?

Очень легко.

merge-коммит содержит информацию о том, какие коммиты мёржились. Их можно найти в логе.

Первый предок — это коммит, на котором стояла текущая ветка до merge, второе — та ветка, которая вливалась в текущую (или последний её коммит, если вы её уже удалили).

Создаёте на первом предке новую временную ветку, и переключаетесь на неё. Заново делаете merge.

Для самоконтроля сравниваете с предыдущей попыткой merge.

Если всё хорошо, сбрасываете основную ветку на новый merge, а временную удаляете. Готово.

Если опять не правильно, сбрасываете временную ветку в иcходное положение, и повторяете merge.

Как только на неудачный merge-коммит не будет ссылаться ни одна ветка, он исчезнет из лога. А через пару недель будет удалён сборщиком мусора.

Comment: А как "сбросить основу ветку на новый мерж"?

Comment: Переключиться на эту ветку и выполнить `git reset --hard <новое место>`. В качестве <новое место> можно указать хэш коммита или имя ветки, стоящей на нём.